# Cartesian vectors to keplerian orbital elements of binary system

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, physics, orbital-elements, python

I am looking to code a a function that converts my 3d position and 3d velocity of a binary system into keplerian orbital elements of the system. I have seen a few other posts on this but they always assume that the orbiting body is moving around a fixed object.
I am using python.

Comment: This is a cool problem! If you can't assume that their center of mass isn't also moving then it's a little more complicated. Are you given anything about their masses? Either both masses or their ratio?

Comment: Where is your origin of the cartesian coordinate system? At one body of the binary system or at their common barycenter? Are keplerian orbital elements applicable to a binary system? Kepler's work was based on the unary solar system with only one central star.

Comment: These papers might be helpful: [1](https://www.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/en/utrip/archive/2011/pdf/13Kyle.pdf), [2](http://ugastro.berkeley.edu/infrared10/adaptiveoptics/binary_orbit.pdf), [3](http://www.jdso.org/volume13/number2/Harfenist_189-199.pdf).

Comment: The standard derivation of the equations of motion for a binary system reduces that system to a single reduced mass moving about a fixed point. It does not matter which point one deems to be fixed; whether (fox example) one assumes the Sun or the Earth to be fixed results in the same equations of motion.

Comment: @uhoh I also think its very cool! I have the fact that the members of the binary system are of equal mass. The origin of the coordinate system is the barycentre of the binary.

Comment: @Uwe Yes the barycenter is at the origin of the Cartesian coordinate system

Comment: @Warrenmovic in that case (equal masses with origin at barycenter) the following should be true $\mathbf{x_1} = -\mathbf{x_2}$ and $\mathbf{v_1} = -\mathbf{v_2}$. In other words you only need one of each; the other is just the negative of the first. In other words you can treat one state vector (e.g. $\mathbf{x_1}$, $\mathbf{v_1}$ ) as an orbit around the origin and use the standard procedure to "assume that the orbiting body is moving around a fixed object" which will be the barycenter at the origin.

Comment: @Warrenmovic  *If however one is not just the negative of the other* then you can't say that the barycenter is fixed at the origin. In that case you've got to solve for both the center of mass location and motion *and* the relative motion of the two around their center of mass.